# Загрузка VHD через GRUB2

Tags: windows, debian, grub, hyper-v

столкнулся с необходимостью установить как вторую ОС Windows XP (для n целей, и собсна её хватит с головой). Через диспетчер дисков на другом компьютере сделал образ vhd и через HyperV установил на диск саму винду. Через HyperV ещё перед установкой отключил все снимки и тд и тп (то есть винт с ОС и всё). Попробовал выполнить подключение и старт с диска через Grub2 и столкнулся ошибкой "Error loading operating system".
Конфигурация загрузчика следующая:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set vhd_name='/win.vhd'
search --no-floppy --set=vhd_dev --file $vhd_name
loopback loop ($vhd_dev)$vhd_name
set root=loop
chainloader +1
```

Попробовал найти что-то дельное на эту тему в интернете, но советы если честно так себе. Имеются подсказки для windows 7, но не охота отдавать больше 5 Гб пространства на диске.

UPD.
Если использовать "chainloader /ntldr" то GRUB пишет "неизвестная файловая система".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтож, спустя две недели я всё таки нашёл решение (почему то гугл не сразу выдаёт нужное).
Соответственно, ссылки на решение (оба рабочие, но может быть загрузчик над загрузчиком (спасибо дядя Гейтс)):
[Тык 1](https://rmprepusb.blogspot.com/2016/04/boot-to-xp-vhd-from-windows-7810-using.html)
[Тык 2](https://reboot.pro/index.php?showtopic=18547)

В соответствии с требованием другого участника, немного внесу корректировки:

0. Установка на VHD делал с помощью стандартных средств Windows, фиксированный размер (и переносил флешкой на другой диск) (Уточню, что именно виртуальные диски Windows корректно работали, VirtualBox сыпал ошибками).
1. Развертывание образа на диск возможно средствами как DISM, так и WinNTSetup, так и установкой через виртуальные машины (в моём случае HyperV).

1.1. При установке образа с HyperV не забудьте поменять драйвера дисковых накопителей на "Стандартные", иначе высок риск синей смерти (а так же включить нужный вам режим (ACHI, RAID), по этим пунктам руководств навалом).

2. Далее, необходимо отсечь область от вашего физического диска. Зачем? А вот беда, загрузчик windows не любит загрузку с чистого vhd на физическом оборудовании через grub.

2.1 С помощью gparted (или удобного вам инструмента) необходимо отсечь область под Windows и отформатировать в формат ntfs (ntfs по причине того, что ext windows не понимает, а fat просто не вместит ваш файл) соответствующего объёма vhd файла и +100мб (так как в эту область будет записан загрузчик). Отформатировав в ntfs, запишите на этот раздел VHD файл, и добавьте к нему с загрузочного диска Windows раздел "/Boot" и "bootmgr" и поместите в корень созданного вами ntfs раздела.

2.2 Отредактируйте запись BCD в папке "/Boot" с помощью BOOTICE ([Тут подробно, пункт 3](https://habr.com/ru/post/228641/)). Если коротко - вы указываете, что будете делать загрузку с VHD файла (для 2000/XP/Vista - указано по ссылка 1 и 2. Важно! Для ОС младше Windows 7 для загрузки с VHD требуется VBOOT. В интернете информация есть, верю, вы сможете найти :) ).

2.3 Выполнив данные процедуры, и записав в корень диска ваш файл VHD, папку "/boot" и файл "bootmgr" и отредактировав файл "BCD", необходимо отредактировать запись в загрузчике grub.

3. Выполнив все эти процедуры, windows с vhd файла должна спокойно загрузиться и работать как полноценная ОС. Преимущество данного метода состоит в том, что MBR не перезаписывается Windows, а grub живёт полноценной жизнью, плюс если вы планируете менять диски или переносить Windows между дисками - это становится совершенно не сложно.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)